# ActionMailer Rails : invitation_email.html.erb file not read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mime

I am using Action Mailers on Rails. I followed the documentation but I can't get invitation_email.html.erb read properly by my browser.
Here is the code on the invitation_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= @sender.first_name %> vous invite à débattre.</h1>
      <p><%= @group_invitation.key %></p>
      <p> Cliquez ici : <%= link_to "Rejoindre", group_accept_invite_url(:key => @group_invitation.key) %>
      </p>
      <div class="button-test">
        button
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code on the group_mailer.rb :

```
  class GroupMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'Logora <contact@logora.fr>'
  layout 'mailer'

  def invitation_email(group_invitation)
    @to = group_invitation.guest
    @sender = group_invitation.sender
    @subject = @sender.first_name + ' vous invite à débattre sur Logora'
    @group_invitation = group_invitation
    m = mail(to: @to, subject: @subject, content_type: "text/html")
  end

end
```

And finally, here is the message I have when I send an email to myself :

Logora 
21:29 (Il y a 7 minutes)
À moi

----==_mimepart_5c32651265cd8_16f563ff3a1d01db04642e Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
test vous invite =C3=A0 d=C3=A9battre.
uh9sNDoDQbYU7ZYixKZHCCjG

Cliquez ici : Rejoindre

button
----==_mimepart_5c32651265cd8_16f563ff3a1d01db04642e Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
test vous invite =C3=A0 d=C3=A9battre. Cliquez ici : Rejoindre
----==_mimepart_5c32651265cd8_16f563ff3a1d01db04642e--

Any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-without-template-rendering) passing `:content_type` also expects that `:body` will be passed (which will skip the template rendering step). So to have the template rendered correctly I suspect you need to remove `content_type: "text/html"`:

```
mail(to: @to, subject: @subject)
```

Comment: It does work if I remove the content_type but it renders invitation_email.erb instead of the invitation_email.html.erb. 
How can I design the invitation_email.erb to custom the sent email ?

Comment: So you do have two separate views: `invitation_email.erb` and `invitation_email.erb.html`? If so then rails it's pick up `invitation_email.erb.html` by default. I recommend to remove one of them if you don't need them, but if you need them both you can you can pass block to mail function with the desired view `mail(to: @to, subject: @subject) do |format| format.html { render 'invitation_email.erb' } end`

Answer (score 1):

`content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` typo, missing some double quotes. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes.